# How do I license the use of a song for my video game?

Tags: copyright, internet, licensing, music

I am having a bit of a dilemma when it comes to the music of my video game, my struggle relies on what do I have to do to get the "rights" of a certain song. What is the process should I follow.

I have heard a song on Soundcloud which I think suits my game theme, the first thing that came into mind is asking the author if I could use his song on my game(giving credits to him on the credits section). If he says I can not use his song, how do I have to approach him with the intention trying to make him sell the rights of that song to me so I can use it on my game (also giving credits to the main author of it).

I am a bit new to this things and I do not know how to handle them properly, I would appreciate a bit of help.

Sorry in advance because I struggle to explain what is in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good overview from Google: *Licensing Songs For Video Games
By Todd Brabec, ASCAP Executive VP of Membership and Jeff Brabec*

> For pre-existing songs, there are a number of different ways to
>   license music in this area depending on the success of the song being
>   used, the type of video game, how the game is distributed and the
>   policies of the manufacturer. Some of the major issues that will be
>   covered in many of the licenses follow. https://www.ascap.com/Home/Music-Career/articles-advice/ascapcorner/corner16.aspx

First, read that to know what you may be dealing with in terms of contracts and licenses. The artist on SoundCloud may not be represented by a music company, such as ASCAP or BMI, but it is good background for what you want to do.

Then contact composer/artist of that song through their Soundcloud profile. They may want to license their music, and if so, you may need to deal with a music company, or at very least, a lawyer to draw up a contract.